# Kubernetes Local PV and PVC bigger than actual disk?

Tags: kubernetes

I currently have a single-node Kubernetes instance running on a VM. The disk attached to this VM is 100GB, but 'df -h' shows that the / partition only has 88GB available (other stuff is used for OS overhead etc...)

I have a kubernetes manifest that creates a 100GB local Persistent Volume.
I also have a pod creating a 100GB Persistent Volume Claim.

Both of these deploy and come up normally even though the entire VM does not even have 100GB available.

To make things even more complicated, the VM is thin provisioned, and only using 20 GB on the actual disk right now...

HOW IS THIS WORKING !?!?

Comment: First, you must say what *storage provider* you are using.

Answer (score 2):

The local provisioner does no size checks, nor is the size enforced anyway. The final "volume" is just a bind mount like with hostPath. The main reason `local` PVs exist is because hostPath isn't something the scheduler understands so in a multi-node scenario it won't restrict topology.